# List View for External Object created using Custom Adapter is throwing an Error

Tags: externalobjects, salesforce-connect

We have created a custom adapter for Salesforce Connect. The "All" list view is working fine, but if I add a filter on the createdate = This Month, it throws me  below error.
[image]
The filter details generated by the adapter are :
filter = Filter:[
columnName = null,
columnValue = null,
subfilters = (
Filter:[columnName=created, columnValue=2021-02-01 08:00:00, subfilters=null, tableName=, type=GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO],
Filter:[columnName=created, columnValue=2021-03-01 08:00:00, subfilters=null, tableName=, type=LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO]
),
tableName=,
type=AND_
],
order=(
Order:[columnName=label, direction=ASCENDING, tableName=],
Order:[columnName=ExternalId, direction=ASCENDING, tableName=]
),
tableSelected=
]

Does anyone has any idea about the cause or solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are running into a gack, the best way to solve this is by having a case logged with [Salesforce Support](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.workcom_contact_support.htm&type=5) as advised in this [developer blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html)

Based on the stack trace and what I see in our internal logs, the issue is occurring in the filter method of DataSource.QueryUtils class

The underlying issue is -

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Character array is missing "e"
> notation exponential mark.

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_DataSource_QueryUtils.htm), The DataSource.QueryUtils class and its helper methods can process query results locally within your Salesforce org. This class is provided for your convenience to simplify the development of your Salesforce Connect custom adapter for initial tests. However, the DataSource.QueryUtils class and its methods aren’t supported for use in production environments that use callouts to retrieve data from external systems. Complete the filtering and sorting on the external system before sending the query results to Salesforce. When possible, use server-driven paging or another technique to have the external system determine the appropriate data subsets according to the limit and offset clauses in the query.

I recommend checking if you are able to locate this class in your org and taking a look at the filter method of the class based on the stack trace. Based on my understanding this has to do with a [Big decimal value](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Edarcy/4851777.5/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigDecimal.java-.html)

```
     if ((c != 'e') && (c != 'E')) {
throw new NumberFormatException("Character array"+ " is missing \"e\" notation exponential mark.");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the helpful information Anudeep!

Comment: Is the DataSource.QueryUtils class available in salesforce open source?

Comment: Yes, see this example for it usage - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connector_start_connection_class.htm. Hope this helps